# uWSGI не перезагружает воркеров

Tags: uwsgi

Проблема в следующем , по заданным параметра в конфиге воркеры отваливаются через опредленное время. Но назад не поднимаются , думаю что то упустил но пока не могу понять. Буду признателен за помощь.
конфиг :

````
[uwsgi]
http = <..>
chdir=/opt/<..>
user = <..>
module = run:application
pyargv = -c /home/<..>
master = true
processes = 5
gevent = 1000
disable-logging = true
log-4xx = true
log-5xx = true
max-requests = 1000                  ; Перезапуск workers после указанного количества запросов
max-worker-lifetime = 3600           ; Перезапуск workers после указанного времени в сек
worker-reload-mercy = 60             ; Время ожидания перед уничтожение процессов workers
harakiri = 300
harakiri-verbose = true
http-timeout = 600
vacuum  = true
enable-threads = true
single-interpreter = true
procname-prefix = <..>
auto-procname = true
logto = /var/log/<...> ```


лог:
worker 1 lifetime reached, it was running for 3601 second(s)
worker 2 lifetime reached, it was running for 3601 second(s)
worker 3 lifetime reached, it was running for 3601 second(s)
worker 4 lifetime reached, it was running for 3601 second(s)
worker 5 lifetime reached, it was running for 3601 second(s)
SIGINT/SIGQUIT received...killing workers...
gateway "uWSGI http 1" has been buried (pid: 25386)
worker 1 buried after 0 seconds
worker 2 buried after 0 seconds
worker 3 buried after 0 seconds
worker 4 buried after 0 seconds
worker 5 buried after 0 seconds
goodbye to uWSGI.
````